# Qt Apps DLLs conflicts with QT Creator DLLs

Tags: windows, qt, dll

We have a Build server with a different QT version than my dev station. So if I install the software builded by the Build server on my dev station, I can not launch the application because the app looks first in my QT Creator directories. I have an error window telling this:

*This application failed to start because it could not find or load the QT platform plugin "windows". Available platform plugins are: minimal, offscreen, windows, windows.*

So I need to rename c:\QT to something like c:\QT.bak and now I can launch the app because it finds the good DLL inside the app install path.

Does anyone know how to fix this? To be able to run an application with a different version of QT than the one in QT Creator.

All the computers use Windows.

Thanks

Comment: That's weird. Do you have c:\qt\something\bin in your global PATH? Or happens QT_PLUGIN_PATH to be set? Also, maybe the installation path of your local Qt happens to be the same as on the build server. Then the deployment would need to take some special measures to make sure the bundled Qt plugins are used, not the development Qt's.

Comment: I dont have any reference to QT folders in my PATH and also QT_PLUGIN_PATH is not set.
On the build server, QT is installed on c:\QT\5.3 and like on my computer.
I run QTDiag on both side and the build server is on QT 5.3.1 and mine is QT 5.3.2.

Comment: Then I'd assume it tries to load the platform plugin from your installation directory instead of the package from the build server. I think tools like Procmon, process explorer, dependency walker could be used to check which plugin library it finds and loads.

Comment: First time I use Process Monitor, it's nice! I can see that the process is looking fist at the QT installation first and after it foudns the dll in the installation directory. Is it possible to make a build and tell it to not do this? To look the installation directory only?

Comment: i have the same problem => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503424/qt5-application-deploy-qwindows-dll-search-path-order

Comment: In earlier days dll's were copied to system locations to allow other users/applications to use the same dll. This has led to the "dll hell". Your problem is another instance of this hell. IMHO: Nowadays there is never a shortage of disk space so *all* non-os dependencies should be copied to the application dir. Windows is guaranteed to look there first.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to put a qt.conf file in the same directory as the deployed exe. In this file you can specify the plugins directory like this:

```
[Paths]
Plugins=.
```

This means that Qt will search for plugins only! in this folder.
In this example the qwindows.dll needs to be in platforms/ like we are used to.

This works perfectly for me, because i have the qt dll's and plugins totally separated for each app i want to deploy. And the installed Qt versions don't interfere anymore.

A really detailed write-up can be found here: http://www.tripleboot.org/?p=536 in section "DLLs loaded by Qt itself a.k.a. plugins:"